# Enabling rake task tracing mode in openshift

Tags: rake, openshift

I'm trying to deploy a Ruby application in Openshift I had this deploy hook for the openshift

The rake is failing in Openshift i.e rake db:migrate I'm taking about

```
set -x
pushd ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR} > /dev/null
export TRACE='--trace'
RAILS_ENV="production" bundle exec rake db:migrate --trace
bundle exec echo $RUBY_VERSION
popd > /dev/null
```

Now trying to run the rake as

```
RAILS_ENV="production" bundle exec rake db:migrate --trace
```

return me output

```
Unknown switches '--trace'
```

and because of heck of it I cant figure out the reason for y the rake is failing any suggestion

Please dont answer me to use heroku can all as the app size is more than 100 MB

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message you're seeing is from bundle:

```
$ rake --trdfsdff
invalid option: --trdfsdff

$ bundle --trace
Unknown switches '--trace'
```

Try invoking bundle as follows:

`RAILS_ENV="production" bundle exec "rake db:migrate --trace"`